# Distributing windows 10 apps from Dynamics portal

Tags: uwp, dynamics-crm, appinstaller

So I'm trying to host an internal UWP app on Dynamics 365.

I'm new to Dynamics, but from what I understand the way to host files (such as installers) is to create a new file Portals => Webfiles, then upload that actual file as part of an attachment to a "note".

I uploaded my .msixbundle file and my .appinstaller file here.

Here's what my .appinstaller file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AppInstaller
    Uri="https://something.microsoftcrmportals.com/myInstaller"
    Version="0.2.4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/appinstaller">
    <MainBundle
        Name="my guid"
        Version="0.2.4.0"
        Publisher="CN=My Name, O=My Name, L=City, S=State, C=US"
        Uri="https://something.microsoftcrmportals.com/msixbundle" />
    <UpdateSettings>
        <OnLaunch HoursBetweenUpdateChecks="0" />
                <AutomaticBackgroundTask/>
    </UpdateSettings>
</AppInstaller>
```

If I go to the urls I can download the correct files, but when I try to run the appinstaller, I get this error:

```
An error occurred while accessing the file from the web. 
Please try downloading and opening the file locally.
```